# how to align column children widgets in left or right side in flutter?

Tags: flutter

i would like to put some text widget in the left side inside a column widget, i have tried to put the textAlign property to the text but it did not work :

```
           Column(
             children: <Widget>[
             Text("some text",textAlign:TextAlign.left),
           ])
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\[flutter\]Why my column alignment is always center?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54513641/flutterwhy-my-column-alignment-is-always-center)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Give the [crossAxisAlignment](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html) property as `start`..

Here's a minimal example for you..

```dart
Column(
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start, // for left side
  // crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end, // for right side
  children: <Widget>[
    Text("some text"),
    Text("other text"),
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use crossAxisAlignment if it is Column

```html
 Column(
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
     children: <Widget>[
     Text("some text",textAlign:TextAlign.left),
  ])
```